# How can I extract a tar.gz file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a Colab Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

As the question states, I'm trying to figure out how I can extract a `.tar.gz` file that is stored in a GCS Bucket from a Google Colab notebook.

I am able to connect to my bucket via:

```
auth.authenticate_user()
project_id = 'my-project'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}
```

However, when I try running a command such as:

```
!gsutil tar xvzf my-bucket/compressed-files.tar.gz
```

I get an error. I know that `gsutil` probably has limited functionality and maybe isn't meant to do what I'm trying to do, so is there a different way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage - GCS does not natively support unpacking a tar archive. You will have to do this yourself either on your local machine or from a Compute Engine VM, for instance

Comment: Okay thanks -- figured that might be the case but was hoping there might be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Dataflow process from a template to decompress a file in your Bucket
The template is called *Bulk decompress Cloud Storage files*

You have to specify file location, output location, failure log, and tmp location

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I'm new to colab and python itself so I'm not certain this is the solution.

!sudo tar -xvf my-bucket/compressed-files.tar.gz